# where to find free casual videos to use in web design as background

Tags: resource-recommendations

I want hd small loop-able casual video which i can put in background. It'd be good for it to be about office work, adventure, playing, community, city life, ocean, sports, school, outside, streets.

I thought i knew a site where there were free videos but i think i forgot. So if you any resources where i can browse it'd be great.

Basically free stock videos that i could use in webdesign.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [All The Free Stock](http://allthefreestock.com/) (scroll down a bit in sidebar to the video section).